# Tuple equality in python suprises

Tags: python, tuples

Didn’t understand why in Python :

```
>>> (1,1) == 1,1
```

Returns

```
>>>  (False, 1)
```

And the statement:

```
>>>  1,1 == (1,1)
```

Returns

```
>>> (1, False)
```

But

```
>>> (1,1) == (1,1)
```

Returns

```
 >>> True
```

Moreover

```
 >>> 1,1,1 == (1,1,1)
```

Returns

```
>>> (1, 1, False)
```

Could someone explain what happening?

Comment: Because `(1, 1) == 1, 1` is equivalent to `((1, 1) == 1), 1` not `(1, 1) == (1, 1)`

Comment: Well, basically it might help if you think of the entire expression as being wrapped in `()` - which makes sense, since the REPL correctly identifies the expression as a tuple type.

Comment: Because the parentheses aren't part of the tuple syntax, they're just normal parentheses used for grouping an expression - you only need them in contexts where the meaning would be different without them (for example, in a function call where the `,` would separate arguments instead). As an exercise, try to predict the result of `1,1==1,1`. Were you right?

Comment: Certainly not a duplicate, but see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45517855/why-does-01-09-return-false-but-01-09-return-0

Comment: Oh, I guess the other thing you have to know is the order of operations between `,` and `==`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, Python is making a tuple of two things:

- The expression: `(1,1) == 1` (Which evaluates to `False`)
- The integer: `1`

Adding parentheses around the order in which actions are performed might help you understand the output:

```
(1,1) == 1,1
```

is the same thing as

```
((1,1) == 1), 1)
```

Here, `(1,1) == 1)`
evaluates to `False`, so you get the output

```
(False, 1)
```

In the same way,

```
1,1 == (1,1)
```

translates to `1, (1 == (1,1))` which becomes

```
(1, False)
```

and

```
1,1,1 == (1,1,1)
```

translates to `1,1, (1 == (1,1,1))` which is

```
(1, 1, False)
```

In this example, Python is making a tuple of three things:

- The two `1`'s
- The expression: `1 == (1,1,1)` (Which evaluates to `False`)

Comment: yep, looks good